# google apps script DriveApp.searchFiles issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to perform a search for files newer than 24 hours using the `DriveApp.searchFiles` Method. Specifically I am using this..

`var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "data*csv" and modifiedDate > "2014-09-12"');`

If I do this it works great however I am trying to use a variable for the string following the `modifiedDate param`.

I am able to set the date string to yesterday's date using this code I found on google.
  `var d = new Date();
   d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
   var d = d.toISOString().substring(0, 10);`

This string is set and displays correctly when I log it with logger, however when I try to use "d" in my code it does not work, it gives an error. Here is what I tried.

`var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "data*csv" and  modifiedDate > "d"');`

From what I can tell either the variable is not set within the quotes or the     `modifiedDate param` does not accept variables or the string type is not correct.

Does anyone know a better or more efficient way to find files in google apps script less than 1 day old?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JimmyJump, try using this line:

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "data*csv" and modifiedDate > "d"');
```

To:

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles("title contains 'data*csv' and  modifiedDate > '"+finalDate+"'");
```

In the first line of code you made the machine think that modifiedDate > d, while in the second line you let your variable get its value at then compare it to modifiedDate > '2016-03-13'

Comment: Man thank you so much. That seems to work. Interesting how the quoting works. I am new to this javascript style coding.